# Can Mathematica help me evaluate an integral over disjoint disks $I = \int_{D_1} \int_{D_2} \log|x-y| dy dx$?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I want to evaluate an integral that involves two disjoint unit disks $D_1$ and $D_2$. $D_1$ is centered at $(-2,0)$ and $D_2$ is centered at $(0,2)$. The integral I want to compute is

$$I = \int_{D_1} \int_{D_2} \log|x-y| dy dx.$$

I looked at the in-built Python integration methods and also the quadpy library but although they have lots of options for integration over a single disk, I couldn't find anything that can help me with integrating over two disjoint disks.

Is it possible to evaluate this integral in Mathematica? I don't need an optimum method, I just need to obtain the value of this integral.

Comment: The exact value of the integral under consideration is $\pi^2\log 4$. The function $\log |x-y|$ is harmonic and the mean value property can be twice applied (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function).

Comment: Mathematica calculates the integral under consideration, producing $\frac{1}{4} \pi ^2 (-1+2 i \pi +\log (16)) $. A bug was submitted by me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NIntegrate[
 Log[Norm[{x1, x2} - {y1, y2}]], 
 {x1, x2} ∈ Disk[{-2, 0}, 1], 
 {y1, y2} ∈ Disk[{2, 0}, 1]
 ]
```

> 13.6822

(the actual result being `13.682176919165677`),

In order to enter `∈`, just type <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

In order to increase the precision, use the option `PrecisionGoal`.

### Edit

Another possibility that relieves *Mathematica* from the need to discretize the disks and that allows her to use higher-order quadrature formulas is to employ polar coordinates on each of the disks:

```
NIntegrate[
 Log[Norm[{r1 Cos[θ1] - 2,r1 Sin[θ1]} - {r2 Cos[θ2] + 2,r2 Sin[θ2]}]] r1 r2,
 {r1, 0, 1}, {θ1, -Pi, Pi},
 {r2, 0, 1}, {θ2, -Pi, Pi},
 Method -> "LocalAdaptive"
 ]
```

Comment: Whoah, that's very nice thanks! I actually just managed to get it going in with some manual change of variables in Python with nquad and I got the result $13.682176927714263$

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Great, I just needed a decent approximation, even the first 4 decimals places would suffice but there's no harm being even more accurate!

Comment: You can also _lower_ the `PrecisionGoal` for more speed...

Comment: Use of Norm is not a good idea since this equals Sqrt[Abs[x1 - x2]^2 + Abs[y1 - y2]^2].

Comment: But `Norm` is what OP asks for. In almost all parts of Mathematics $|x-y|$ for _vectors_ $x$ and $y$ means the Euclidean distance. Only in optimization, it may sometimes denote the vector of the absolute differences.

Comment: Abs is superfluous and slows down the execution.

Comment: Ah, that's what you mean. Could be a valid point. Surprisingly, `NIntegrate[
 Log[Sqrt[(x1 - y1)^2 + (x2 - y2)^2]], {x1, x2} \[Element] 
  Disk[{-2, 0}, 1], {y1, y2} \[Element] Disk[{2, 0}, 1]]` takers _longer_ for execution.

Comment: You are right. Your code is three times faster.

Comment: I am astonished myself. No idea why this happens...

Comment: I think Norm is optimized.

Comment: Sorry I forget to accept this answer!

Comment: No problem. And thanks!