# Does Mathematica have a 'nice' way to evaluate singular double integrals over line segments?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I want to perform a double integration over a line segment in 2D and I am wondering if can it be done in Mathematica. An added difficulty is that the integral is singular.

$$I = \int_{(4,4)}^{(2,8)}\int_{(4,4)}^{(2,8
)} \log|x-y| \,\mathrm{d}y \, \mathrm{d}x.$$

I am not that concerned with efficiency here, I would just like to have a nice way to integrate these types of integrals compared to how I have to do it in Python which involves analytically regularizing them first to deal with the singular integrands and then transformation to reference intervals before finally coding the actual integration.

So can this be done 'nicely' in Mathematica?

**Edit**
My Mathematica code that gives the incorrect answer:

```
  NIntegrate[
     Log[Norm[{x1, x2} - {y1, y2}]], 
     {x1, x2} ∈ Line[{{4,4},{2,8}}], 
     {y1, y2} ∈ Line[{{4,4},{2,8}}]
     ]
```

Comment: What do the integral limits mean?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher The limits mean integrate over the straight line segment from the point $[3,3]$ to the point $[2,5]$.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Actually I just noticed it can be done using the method you used in a previous question I asked here - https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/190728/can-mathematica-help-me-evaluate-an-integral-over-disjoint-disks-i-int-d-1

Comment: However it gives me the result: -0.0435146 whereas I get -0.042677 in Python! I get alot of warnings from Mathematica too before it gives me that result and the 'error estimate': 0.008498.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting the singularities on the boundary of the integration domain makes `NIntegrate` take care of them. Plus, this utilizes the fact that the integrant is symmetric, so that the work can be reduced by half.

```
p = {2, 8};
q = {4, 4};
2 Norm[p - q]^2 NIntegrate[
  Log[Norm[(p (1 - t) + t q) - (p (1 - s) + s q)]], 
  {t, 0, 1}, {s, t, 1}]
```

> -0.0426773

If you are in need of integrating this integrant over more general and more complicated domains and if speed is an issue, the [fast multipole method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_multipole_method) and related techniques might be your friends.

Comment: Ok cool, I got the same result in Python! I will edit my original post to show the Mathematica code I used that gave the wrong result. It would be great if you could identify why it is wrong as I would like to able to compute integrals in this form.

Comment: I plan to implement the FMM eventually but for the moment I'm just trying to make sure all my singular integral evaluations are correct!

Comment: Do you think the edited code I posted in the OP can be 'fixed' to give the correct answer? It would be great if I could evaluate integrals using expressions in Mathematica like that rather than having to transform them first like I have to do with Python.

Comment: I believe that `NIntegrate` branches to finite element techniques whenever a `Region` or a `MeshRegion` appears as domain, i.e., the domain is discretized and standard quadrature rules are applied, probably in conjunction with local refinement techniques. But these quadrature rules fail for singular integrals. In total, I don't think that `NIntegrate`'s tools for regions are on par with its classical capabilities (parameterized integrals like I showed to you).

Comment: But I am actually not an expert in `NIntegrate`, so I don't really know what happens under the hood.

Comment: Ok, its a pity its inaccurate far off for the integral in Region form as that's a very convenient format for verification purposes.

Comment: I'm not sure if this warrants an answer or not but `NIntegrate[Log[Norm[{x1, x2} - {y1, y2}]] /. Abs -> Identity, {x1, x2} ∈ Line[{{4, 4}, {2, 8}}], {y1, y2} ∈ Line[{{4, 4}, {2, 8}}]]` gets preprocessed to `NIntegrate[20 Log[2 Sqrt[5] Sqrt[(x1 - x2)^2]], {x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}]` internally and this is where it chokes.

Comment: @ChipHurst Hm. Interesting. From _there_ one could go by `NIntegrate[20 Log[2 Sqrt[5] Sqrt[(x1 - x2)^2]], {x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1},
 Exclusions -> {x1 == x2}
 ]`. Unfortunately, `NIntegrate` with regions refused to accept a setting for `Exclusions`.

Comment: Yes, it seems it does not propagate options to the second `NIntegrate` call.